# Бот телеграмм, ответ на ввод число.месяц.год (datetime)

Tags: python, datetime

Прошу помочь с куском кода для тг бота. Нужно, чтобы при вводе любой даты рождения в формате 01.05.2007, бот выдавал ответ. Не могу понять в чем затык в куске кода ниже:

```py
import datetime

b = datetime.datetime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def  answer_to_text(message):
    if message.text == "Узнать возраст":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите дату рождения в формате: число.месяц.год. Например: 01.01.1989")
    elif message.text == "b":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "бла бла бла")
        
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Так же всплывает ошибка:

> TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Зачем Вам строка `b = datetime.datetime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")` ?

Comment: b = datetime.datetime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"). datetime не содержит ничего и возвращать также нечего, поэтому здесь будет ошибка. Вы можете это заменить, допустим, на b = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

Comment: Спасибо, уже пробовал так, все равно нет ответа от бота.  То есть, бот присылает :"Введите дату рождения в формате: число.месяц.год. Например: 01.01.1989", пользователь отправляет дату, допустим, 02.04.2000 и ничего не происходит. Не понимаю, что нужно подставить вместо "b".